# css is not loaded on IE when the css in the body

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a case that I want the css to be in the body not in the header, because the header is for all pages and each page have a different css file.

I have a problem that the style is working on chrome and firefox but it is not working on IE11.

I tried to use F12 to debug the problem and I discovered the problem.

when I click on the div class=waitingTime" on IE 11, the style is not appeear on the right view.

but when I do the same thing on chrome and firefox, the style is appears on right.

#### IE 11

[image]

#### Chrome

[image]

you can see that the code of adding the css file is above the div

#### Update

For people who can't see the images, I upload them here 
http://postimg.org/image/dd2p19gkh/

http://postimg.org/image/c5a0dntvn/

#### Update 2

this is how I add the css

```
<link href="http://localhost:8082/ParkingProject/public/css/waitingTimes" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<div class="waitingTime">
</div>
```

Comment: mm... can't debug images... :)

Comment: @TilwinJoy the idea is to show you the problem, if you need more explanation kindly tell me

Comment: @TilwinJoy I upddated the question with  better imgae links

Comment: Yea i get that part... are you sure you took the screenshots with the same code, after it fully loaded in both browsers? cause this seems really weird.

Comment: @TilwinJoy yes the same code exactly, and the problem is when I tried to give you a jsfiddle, it works on the jsfiddle because on the jsfiddle I add the css to the `css area` but in my code the css is added into the html mark up

Comment: It sure is better image links :D but i don't think it'll last longer in SO..

Comment: I think IE just does not render link tags which are not in the head and there is nothing you can do about it, except maybe use JS to inject style references into the head.

Comment: can you post the line of code you're using in markup to add the css..? (*if you're adding an external file*)

Comment: <link href="xxx/yyy.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> In IE Are you sure about closing link and check the slashes are forward

Comment: @Sam1604 I just updated the question with the code, I copied the code exactly from F12 in iE11. hope it helps

Comment: @HaukurHaf why this super extra bad browser does this? it is so stupid, is there any other way beside the js to teach this browser to use the css?

Comment: It seems like a bad solution that you want the css in the body. Just add a class to the body according to the page <body class="page-1"> and in your css use: .page-1 div.i-want-to-style

Comment: Close the link `</link>`

Comment: @Sam1604 I found the problem myself, check my answer please

Comment: @DannyvanHolten I found the problem myself, check my answer please

Comment: @TilwinJoy I found the problem myself, check my answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem

The file is waitingTime.css but I forgot to say `.css`

chrome and firefox so clever to udnerstand it but IE is stupid :) so when I added `.css` it works

Comment: @DannyvanHolten my friend don't argue that IE is stupid, it is soooooooooooooooooooooooo stupid. ;)

Comment: @DannyvanHolten I am one girl working on simple project, but IE is a big project has been existed for more than 10 years, and more than 1000 developers are working on it.

Comment: And still it is not smart enough to automatically fix your stupid mistakes. Stupid, stupid IE. :-S

Comment: @GolezTrol do you invest in IE or what? plus why did you downvote please? my answer is the answer that works

Answer (score 1):

You can use `link` tags in the body (only in HTML5) documents, but only when they have an `itemprop` attribute, not when they have a `rel` attribute.

So, your HTML is invalid. It's very nice of Chrome that it accidentally processes your page correctly, but you cannot blame IE for not doing so.

See also 
[Can I use `<link>` tags in the body of an HTML document?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55130/can-i-use-link-tags-in-the-body-of-an-html-document)

Comment: I found the problem myself, check my answer

Comment: So Chrome automagically fixes *two* of your mistakes. Nice! Still, it would be a good thing to fix them. Even though apparently the three major browsers support it, it doesn't make it right, and it might break in any future version.